# `defface` and `custom-set-faces`

Tags: faces, custom

Noob here. In my `.emacs.d/custom.el` I have stuff like:

```lisp
(defface delim-mismatch `((t (:foreground "red"))))

(custom-set-faces
  '(show-paren-mismatch delim-mismatch)
  ...
  )
```

But it throws "Wrong type argument: listp, delim-mismatch". I can't seem to find an example of using `defface`-defined faces in `custom-set-faces` by name.

Comment: Why define `delim-mismatch`? Why not do it directly like this: `(custom-set-faces '(show-paren-mismatch ((t (:foreground "red")))))`? Or even better, customize it interactively: `M-x customize-face<RET>show-paren-mismatch<RET>`. In particular, the default seems to be white foreground on purple background. If you just change the foreground to red, the paren becomes almost invisible: red on purple is not a good combination. If you do it interactively, you can experiment with the colors before saving the customization.

Comment: This is an example. I apply the style to several targets. Also I'm using a different theme so the visibility is not an issue.

Comment: I don't understand. (1) Your `custom-file` should be only for Customize to write to. Put your `defface`s in your init file or some other file that you load from it. (2) Your `defface` definition is no good. See `C-h f defface`. (3) It's not clear (to me) what you're really trying to do.

Comment: (3) How can I actually use a face defined by `defface` -- apply it to some other face (overwrite it?) Sorry, I can't find what type of object `show-paren-mismatch` is... (2) Hmm, it didn't give me an error. (3) Gotcha, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Drew](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/105/drew) pointed out, your `defface` definition is no good, but let’s ignore that for now.

One has to assign a [*face spec*](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Faces.html) to a face, which `delim-mismatch` is not.  There is, however, a way to construct a face spec that inherits from another face by using the `:inherit` [face attribute](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Attributes.html).  Alternatively, faces [can be aliased](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Functions.html).

This gives us three options:

```lisp
;; use the `:inherit' face attribute
(defface delim-mismatch '((t :foreground "red"))
  "My custom delim mismatch face.")
(custom-set-faces
 '(show-paren-mismatch ((t :inherit delim-mismatch))))
```

```lisp
;; define the face spec instead of the face itself
(defvar delim-mismatch-face-spec '((t :foreground "red"))
  "My custom delim mismatch face spec.")
(custom-set-faces
 `(show-paren-mismatch ,delim-mismatch-face-spec))
```

```lisp
;; alias the faces
(defface delim-mismatch '((t :foreground "red"))
  "My custom delim mismatch face.")
(put 'show-paren-mismatch 'face-alias 'delim-mismatch)
```

The first option is the one that’s most commonly used as it’s the most flexible of the three.

Comment: Thank you! This perfectly answers my question. I had tried `:inherit` similar to how you have here, but one possible limitation is that: attributes already attached to the face must be explicitly overwritten/negated in the inherited face spec, whereas the other two approaches completely overwrite, which (in my case) is simpler.